# IBOutlet nil after closing NSWindow sheet - swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, delegates, iboutlet

I have an NSWindowController class connected to an .xib that I present as a sheet with the following method in my main ViewController:

```
func openSheet() {
    var modalSheet = NSWindowController()
    modalSheet = modalWindow(windowNibName: "modalWindow") as modalWindow
    self.view.window!.beginSheet(modalSheet.window!, completionHandler: nil)
    modalSheet.window!.delegate = self
}
```

`modalWindow` being the name of the `NSWindowController` sheet class.

In my modalWindow class I have the following method:

```
@IBAction func cancel(sender: AnyObject) {
    var delegate: NSWindowDelegate? = ViewController() as NSWindowDelegate
    var nsn = NSNotification(name: "", object: nil)
    println("Closing Modal Window. Saved data: \(data)")
    self.window!.close()
    delegate!.windowWillClose!(nsn!)
}
```

Now when I call the protocol method in my main ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet var path1: NSTextField!

func windowWillBeginSheet(notification: NSNotification) {
    path1.stringValue = "abc"
}
```

`path1` shows up as nil. 
Any help or guidance on fixing the issue of `path1` showing up as nil would be greatly appreciated.